# KeyCloak - Login an user with only username and a trusted call

Tags: keycloak

I have a Portal APP where user can login with classic USERNAME + PASSWORD or use an external IDP (think something like Google or other OPENID).

After the authentication, the EXTERNAL IDP return to a specific URL of APP PORTAL. I then need to LOG the user IN knowing ONLY the username of user.

What I was thinking is a login system where the APP PORTAL, using some "admin-token", can log an user knowing only his username.

[image]

What I found is some sort of "impersonating" system but is not what I really need. I want that KeyCloak log the user like it was a native username + password login with a valid session.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: don"t try to invent something, just use existing protocol for such case, saml, oidc, oauth2, etc

Comment: The only way using standard approach, is transform my (Django) APP in an OPENID provider so KeyCloak can use it as provider. But online I found only tutorial on how authenticate in with an external OPENID.

Comment: A better way is to use your existing DB with login pwd as the db of keycloack and use keycloak to connect to your Django APP